# Using Additional Parameter in Unique Check for Angular Directive

Tags: validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So, I'm looking to create my first angular directive for a validation check.  Essentially I want to ensure an user name is unique.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865401/151084) is perfect for my first pass, and works as expected for creating a new user.

I'd like this also to work for users who want to change their user name.  On the server side, I would write code to check that the user name doesn't exist in the database *for any user other than the current user*.  In other words, if a user is modifying their profile, and the form has a group of fields that include user name, I don't want to form to be invalid if the username already exists, since the *reason* it exists is that the current user already has it.

So what I would like to do is pass the userId (an integer PK) as a parameter in the ajax call in addition to the user name.  The userId exists on the $scope, but I don't know how to modify the directive to allow me to pass additional information.

I would imagine the markup would look something like the following?

```
    <input type="email" ng-model="userEmail" 
           name="userEmail" required unique-email="userId"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the uniqueEmail directive does not create a new scope, you can pass the name of the property as shown (`unique-email="userId"`) and then use [$eval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24eval) in your link function:

```
var userId = scope.$eval(attrs.uniqueEmail);
```

Note that I'm assuming the link function parameter is named `attrs` (not `attr`).