# Name conventions in angualrjs directives

Tags: angularjs

This works for me (server-side validation example):

[AngularJS: integrating with server-side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864887/angularjs-integrating-with-server-side-validation)

But, I decided to ask additional question.

In that example we use **unique-email** directive:

```
<input type="email" ng-model="userEmail" name="userEmail" required unique-email/>
```

But when creating the directive, we use **uniqueEmail**:

```
app.directive('uniqueEmail', function($http) { ..
```

Why? Is it related somehow to name conventions / rules in names? How does angular know where to look and how to connect one to another?

I just wonder because when I used `<input ... required uniqueEmail` it does not work. Until I typed "unique-email"

Same if I type:

```
app.directive('unique-email', function($http) {
```

It will not work until I type `uniqueEmail`

So there is no chance to use one style name when use directive and when define it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be
>   prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant.

So, yes it is an angular convention.

Comment: So there is no chance to use one style name when use directive and when define it?

Answer (score 5):

It is html convention to use only lower case for tags and attributes (partly because HTML5 is not case sensitive.  class="" is the same as ClaSS="").  Angular didn't want to constrain your directive names to lower case.  So it allows the use of upper case within Angular and then handles turning those names into the html standard snake case for you.

So you get naming flexibility, and improved readability, in Angular while staying compliant with html naming standards.

Note, that if you only use lower case names you won't have to worry about the name conversion.  Of course, that'll likely come at the expense of readability of your Angular code.