# AngularJs API references

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When i look up the [API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) references of AngularJS, the directive uses capital Letter in the API documentation and without hyphen

for example **ngApp** is not like **ng-app**

When we code it we code it like this

```
<html ng-app>

<html>
```

Why it is done like this ? it it purposefully

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name conventions in angualrjs directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503121/name-conventions-in-angualrjs-directives)

Comment: Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model). See angular docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).