# $attrs undefined angular directive for comparing password and password repeat

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm learning mean stack development and following along a video tutorial course. Everything was going fine till I went across this error while trying to match two password fields. "Password" and "Confirm Password"
I'm writing the exact code as the tutorial yet I'm getting following errors in the command line (Gulp serve)

> error "$attrs" is not defind no-undef
>
> error "$attrs" is not defind no-undef

Here's the code

```
export function CompareToDirective($parse) {
'ngInject'
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
        var mainModel = $parse(attrs.compareTo);
        var secondModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue) {
            ngModel.$setValidity($attrs.name, newValue === mainModel(scope));
        });

        scope.$watch(attrs.compareTo, function (newValue) {
            ngModel.$setValidity($attrs.name, newValue === secondModel(scope));
        });
    }
}
```

}

EDIT

Here's the form I' trying to validate just in case

```
<form name="register">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" ng-model="pwd">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password Confirm</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" compareTo="pwd" name="pwdConfirm" ng-model="pwdConfirm">
                </div>
                <span ng-show="register.pwdConfirm.$invalid">Passwords do not match</span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: remove "$" from $attrs.. just use attrs

Comment: Are you sure it's not just `attrs` ... that's what you have in your function definition.

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/AG6q8O6OL.png
Here is the screen shot of the code from the tutorial. which has "$attrs"

When I remove $ from "attrs"
The errors go but still the form doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was able to get it work. Please find below code

```
.directive("compareto", function($parse) {
  return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
    var mainModel = $parse(attrs.compareto);
    var secondModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue) {
          ngModel.$setValidity(attrs.name, newValue === mainModel(scope));
    });

    scope.$watch(attrs.compareto, function (newValue) {
        ngModel.$setValidity(attrs.name, newValue === secondModel(scope));
    });
}
}
});
```

and form will be

```
<form name="register">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" ng-model="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password Confirm</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" compareto="pwd" name="pwdConfirm" ng-model="pwdConfirm">
            </div>
            <span ng-show="register.pwdConfirm.$invalid">Passwords do not match</span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: I'm exporting the function `CompareToDirective` but now I don't seem to be understand how would I make it into a function I can export. can you please make it like I can exprort it with the same name into `index.module.js`.
Sorry from being a noob

Comment: in your code in form try changing compareTo="pwd" to compare-to="pwd".

Comment: Thanks @pawan 
Its get to be working now, I replace my this code
`return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
        var mainModel = $parse(attrs.compareTo);
        var secondModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue) {
            ngModel.$setValidity($attrs.name, newValue === mainModel(scope));
        });

        scope.$watch(attrs.compareTo, function (newValue) {
            ngModel.$setValidity($attrs.name, newValue === secondModel(scope));
        });
    }
}`
to yours.

Comment: Can you help me know what is the difference :(

Comment: The issue was due to naming convention used for directive name compareTo. Please refer [this for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503121/name-conventions-in-angualrjs-directives).. If you use small case for directive, you won't have to worry about the directive names convention. But since you were using compareTo as your directive name in HTML and for attrs.compareTo it was not working.

Comment: I see the only difference is `compareTo` and `compareto`
Is there somethinga bout case sensitivity that it was not working>
A small detail would be appreciated

Comment: I see. Thanks you so much for your help.