# How to show a warning message when user leaves without saving changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive that watches for `$locationChangeStart` events and shows the user a message if the form has unsaved changes. The problem is that the event handler is never triggered. Here is simplified version of my code in `notify-on-location-change.js`

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';


    angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('notifyOnLocationChange', ['$scope', 'event', 'next', 'current', function ($scope, event, next, current) {

        $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {                
            if (true) {
                alert('Unsaved data!');
            }                

        });

        $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {                
            if (true) {
                alert('Unsaved data!');
            }                

        });


    }]);

})();
```

I then mark the form I want to trigger the warning:

```
 <form name="detailsForm" ng-submit="$ctrl.onSubmit()" novalidate notifyOnLocationChange>
```

`notify-on-location-change.js` is included in index.html

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the form attribute to `notify-on-location-change`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503227/584846 for more details