# Custom validation directive overrides other validations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have created a custom validation that verifies if the user exists or not. If the user does not exist, this validation must be validated. It is a simple GET query that returns JSON content.

The problem is that this validation seems to override the others. If the user **does not** already exist but has less than 3 caracters, normally the field shouldn't be validated but it is ! If I remove the custom validation that I have created, the problem disappears and the length validation works.

Here's my code:

```
angular.module('userRegistrationApp').directive('usernameNotExist', function($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue){
                var user = viewValue;

                $http({method: 'GET', url: '/register/doesUserOrEmailExist/' + user }).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                       if(data.doesUserOrEmailExist == false) {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('usernameNotExist', true);
                            return viewValue;
                        }else {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('usernameNotExist', false);
                            return undefined
                        }
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('usernameNotExist', false);
                        return undefined;
                    })

            });
        }
    }
});

<input type="text" id="sonata_user_registration_form_username" name="sonata_user_registration_form[username]" required="required" maxlength="255" pattern=".{2,}" class="form-control" username-not-exist="" ng-minlength="3" ng-focus="setFocus('username')" ng-model="userRegistrationService.username">
```

I followed exactly what they said in the documentation but I get this error !

Comment: I highly doubt you have done it exactly as they in the docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution. It is inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865401/2573319

Try the following directive and see if it works for you !

```
angular.module('userRegistrationApp').directive('usernameNotExist', function($http) {
    var timeout;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                    var user = value;
                    // if there was a previous attempt, stop it.
                    if(timeout)
                        clearTimeout(timeout);

                    // start a new attempt with a delay to keep it from
                    // getting too "chatty".
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                        // call to some API that returns { isValid: true } or { isValid: false }
                        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/register/doesUserOrEmailExist/' + user }).success(function(data) {
                            if(data.doesUserOrEmailExist == false) {
                                ctrl.$setValidity('usernameNotExist', true);
                            }
                            else {
                                ctrl.$setValidity('usernameNotExist', false);
                            }
                        }).error(function(data) {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('usernameNotExist', false);
                        });
                    }, 200);
                })

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahhh...don't use `setTimeout` in an AngularJS app !

Comment: What do you suggest ? Just removing it ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that the solution is to use

> `scope.$watch`

instead of

> `ctrl.$parsers.unshift`

It seems to me that `ctrl.$parsers.unshift` will make your custom validation executed before other validations, then if your custom validation fails, `return undefined;` will set the model value to undefined so that other validations won't have the valid value to deal with.

`scope.$watch` will trigger your custom validation after all other validation passed.

I haven't found anything to support this from angular docs yet, this is based on my debug experience.