# How would one write an Angular directive for a 'Required If' scenario?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm working on understanding how to use Angular Directives to implement front-end validations.  While I'm familiar with the way that directives generally work, what I'm having a hard time finding in any tutorial, blogpost, or even the actual Angular docs, is how to meaningfully implement a useful validation.  (By that, I mean one that isn't already there, as in [this basic tutorial for how to implement a validation attribute](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/12/angular-js-custom-validation-via.html).

The most common of these in my experience, is a 'Required If' scenario.  If I have Text Field A and Text Field B in my form, and Text Field A has a value, my business rules tell me that Text Field B must have a value.  However, the various tutorials for validation directives have all only relied on the element that they are tied to.

**Question:** I suspect that I am approaching the problem of how to implement something like a Required If validation completely wrong.  In the Angular way, what is the correct way to require a value in a form if and only if a field that it's dependent on has a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some additional experimentation today.  A coworker prompted me with a different situation, that finally led to me solving the problem for myself.

I was fundamentally looking at the problem in the wrong way, for starters - specifically, I was looking at it in the jQuery way, by expecting the directive to somehow expose ways to read individual form elements.  This isn't necessarily correct, since we have a scope that we can evaluate.

Here is the pre-1.3 Angular directive code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('someController', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.valueA = '';
        $scope.valueB = 'Chicken';
    }
]);

app.directive('requiredIf', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, model) {
                // Read the companion attribute 'otherModelName'
                var otherModelName = attr.otherModelName;

                scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function (value) {
                    var isValid = checkAgainstDependentModel(value);
                    model.$setValidity('requiredIf', isValid);
                });

                function checkAgainstDependentModel(value) {
                    // Assumes that the scope exposes a property with the passed-in
                    // model name as its name
                    var field = scope[otherModelName];

                    var isValid = true;
                    if(field != null || field != '')
                        if(value == null || value == '')
                            isValid = false;

                    return isValid;
                }
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

...In markup we would use it like so:

```
<form name='someForm'>
    <input type='text' name='mainField' ng-model='valueA' />
    <input type='text' name='subordinateField' ng-model='valueB' required-if other-model-name='valueA' />
    <span style='color=red' ng-if='someForm.subordinateField.$error.requiredIf'>
        (Required!)
    </span>
</form>
```

<strike>This pattern can be expanded to various other custom validations, pre-1.3.  My research has shown me that Angular 1.3 will remove the `$parsers` and `$formatters` in favor of `$validators` and `$asyncValidators`.</strike>

EDIT: Instead of using `$formatters/$parsers`, a better idea I ran across is to instead do a `scope.$watch` on the associated `ngModel`.  Since this is a pre-1.3 implementation, we can still just do `model.$setValidity('thing', isValid);`  This is based on the answer [to the question of how best to achieve remote validation pre-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864887/angularjs-integrating-with-server-side-validation).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using ng-if to add the next form element only if the previous form element is valid.  The second element won't exist in the DOM unless the first element is valid.