# AngularJS Conditionally set input as required within directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a directive that allows me to apply changes to a group of HTML elements if the element is required. Specifically, if the element is required, it should apply a "required" class to the label and the "required" attribute to the input. Using a sample I found, I have a start, but I am stuck.

The problem I am having is the data that determines if a particular input is required or not is in the scope and changes based on what's in a shopping cart (i.e. if only digital products are in the cart, no shipping address is required).

Here's my working sample which works fine, except I don't know how / where to get access to the scope so I can conditionally apply the required attributes.

The directive:

```js
app.directive('setRequired', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000, 
        compile: function compile(elem, attrs) {

            // TO_DO - look at the configuration values from
            // the scope to determine if the element is required.
            // How and where do I get access to the scope??

            // Add required class to the label, if found
            var label, labelNg;
            label = elem[0].querySelector("label");
            if (label) {
                labelNg = angular.element(label);
            }

            if (labelNg) {
                labelNg.addClass("required");
            }

            // Add the required property to the first input element, if found
            var input, inputNg;
            input = elem[0].querySelector("input");
            if (input) {
                inputNg = angular.element(input);
            }

            if (inputNg) {
                if (!inputNg.prop("required")) {
                    inputNg.prop('required', true);
                }
            }

            elem.removeAttr("set-required");

            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    $compile(iElement)(scope);
                }

            };
        }
    };
});
```

The HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group" set-required>
    <label translate>Address</label>
    <input name="address_1" type="text" ng-model="customer.address_1">
</div>
```

Comment: so you simply want access to the controller scope within directive right !

Comment: I'd like to supply one element from the scope into the directive so the directive can respond as it changes, and have it passed in using a mechanism where I don't hard-code the scope property name (so the directive can be reusable).

Comment: Have you tried using ng-required directive on your fields and make required or not based on Boolean condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would one write an Angular directive for a 'Required If' scenario?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899359/how-would-one-write-an-angular-directive-for-a-required-if-scenario)