# Handle angular validation errors after form submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, api

I have an angular form, where I submit some data to our API. The api does some extra validation checks on fields and reports them back if there is something wrong with the field.

I catch the error on save and put errors on the proper fields with form.field.$setValidity("", true);

But if the user changes the field to correct the fault, the validity error isn't removed. Does anyone have an idea how to remove the error after the field is updated by the user?

Comment: Have you added validation attribute to the component of the form like <input ng-model="text" ng-model="model" ng-required>?

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864887/angularjs-integrating-with-server-side-validation

Comment: I looked at the solution in the other question. But I would really like to sent the whole form and then mark the fields invalid for the fields that are invalid. And let the user correct the form after it comes back invalid. But changing the field doesn't set it back to valid again. Do I need to keep track of the invalid options I set with the $setValidity()? And clear them after typing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<form name="form" ng-submit='formSubmitted = true;'>
<input type="text" name="mobileNumber" required/>
<span ng-if="formSubmitted && form.mobileNumber.$invalid" >Enter mobile number</span>
</form>
```