# Angularjs server side validation of multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have made an attempt to create a custom validation directive to validate two items simultaneously at server side.

I have two values `regNumber` and `regDate` that have to be validated along with each other. So when user enters both of them correctly,they are validate. But, if one of them is entered incorrectly, they both have to be invalidated.

To accomplish the goal, I have written a the following directive base on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864887/angularjs-integrating-with-server-side-validation).

Everything is working fine except When I enter  both together `regNumber` and `regDate` incorrectly. Then, even If I change them both to correct values, still they are invalidated.

By "Everythin is working fine" I mean when I enter an invalid value for `regNumber`  and a valid value for `regDate`, and change the `regNumber` back to a valid value, it works fine and vice versa(first regDate and then regNumber).

I think `$setValidatity` will be set for the latest input which has been changed and not for both of them but even if my guess is true, I don't know how to solve it. :D

**Directive:**

```
 osiApp.directive('uniqueOrder', function ($http, $rootScope) {
        var toId;
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function (value) {
                    if (scope.osiRequest.regDate) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueOrder', true);
                        if (toId) clearTimeout(toId);
                        toId = setTimeout(function () {
                            $http({
                                method: 'GET',
                                url: $rootScope.baseAddress + '/ValidateOrderRegistrationNumber/Get',
                                params: {
                                    orderRegistrationDate: scope.osiRequest.regDate ,
                                    orderRegistrationNumber: scope.osiRequest.regNumber

                                }
                            }).success(function (isValid) {
                                ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueOrder', isValid);
                            });
                        }, 200);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="myForm.regNumber.$error.uniqueOrder || 
               myForm.regDate.$error.uniqueOrder ? 'has-error' : ''">
    <input class="form-control"
          name="regNumber" ng-model="osiRequest.regNumber" unique-order>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group" ng-class="myForm.regNumber.$error.uniqueOrder || 
               myForm.regDate.$error.uniqueOrder ? 'has-error' : ''">
    <input class="form-control"
          name="regDate" ng-model="osiRequest.regDate " unique-order>
    </div>
```

Comment: Making a directive creates a brand new scope, so you should not have access to both `regDate` and `regNumber` in your link method (check your params). You need to implicitly bind both to your directive scope.

Comment: I see. But, How can I "implicitly bind both to the directive scope"?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @NicolasMoise you have to be able to access both model in your directive, few ways to achieve this :

1. Adding both ng-model osiRequest.regDate & osiRequest.regNumber as your directive attributes unique-order. Check "scope" parameter for directive.
2. Access parent controller scope from directive by using $parent ( not ideal )

Comment: Will you please provide some code sample for the first solution?