# AngularJS clear errors before validation

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have angular validation and server side validation (like username taken).
I am binding server errors to form elements.

```
$scope.registerFormSubmit = function()
{
    if (isEmpty($scope.registerForm.$error))
    {
        $http({
            url: '/profile/register',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: toArray($scope.form),
        }).error(function(response){
            if (false == is(response.formErrors)) return;
            for (var k in $scope.registerForm)
            {
                if (!is(response.formErrors[k]))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        $scope.registerForm[k].$error = {};
                    }catch(e){

                    }

                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.registerForm[k].$error[response.formErrors[k]] = 1;
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

The problem is when user change model (ex. username) errors from server still exists after submit clicked. So, ajax can't be send because condition

```
isEmpty($scope.registerForm.$error)
```

Is always false because form has errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty comprehensive discussion of using Angular with server side validation here: [AngularJS: integrating with server-side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864887/angularjs-integrating-with-server-side-validation)

A lighter-weight solution I've used:

- Key the errors so you know they're a server error. To preserve knowledge of the specific error, you could do something like this instead in your current error handler:

`$scope.registerForm[k].$error.server = 'Error-specific string. Could also be an object';`

- Clear the server errors on input change. Here's a sample directive to do it on keydown:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('serverError', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.on('keydown', function() {
          return ngModel.$setValidity('server', true);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="coolguy" server-error />
```

- Then you can just apply the `server-error` directive to all your form elements.